# Dropbox Dropin Saver - Can I upload files from a computer?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox's Dropin [Saver](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver) to upload files into my Dropbox account. Can I upload a file from my computer (not from a web site)?

Answer (score -1):

No. Presumably the user could just do that on `dropbox.com` if they wanted?

Comment: So if I want to upload a file from my mobile device directly from my application ןs there a way to do it without surfing to the dropbox.com (maybe by using another API)?

Comment: Oh, certainly! The Core API and Sync API both support this.

Answer (score -1):

As finding the straight-forward solution to your question is still not easy, let me point you to the Dropbox API Explorer:

1. Create a Dropbox Web-App [with a few clicks](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/).
2. Use its Access Token in the [Dropbox API Explorer/upload](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_upload) to create a code snippet including a preview for what you are looking for.
3. Use the cURL or Python code in your code.